# How to output result of rgb2hsv (causes colour values to be between 0-1) as a uint8 image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to convert 2 RGB images to HSV images then calculate the difference between the two images saturation and output this resulting image as a `uint8` image. Here is the code I've tried but `uint8` is converting the intensities to 1 or 0 resulting in a binary image essentially.

```
inputImage = rgb2hsv(inputImage);
background = rgb2hsv(background);

sDiff = imabsdiff(background(:,:,2), inputImage(:,:,2));

sDiff = uint8(sDiff);

figure, imshow(sDiff, []);
```

Its outputting a binary image though. I tried:

```
  gDiff = double(sDiff) * 255;
```

But the resulting intensities are either 255 or 0.

Comment: there is a typo, imshow(sDiff,[])?

Comment: nah i did that asking the question same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sDiff = uint8(sDiff.*256);` to convert it to uint8 format